# How can i use additional fields to get jwt token

Tags: python, django, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

i use https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

i have such code

```
User = get_user_model()

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    ROLE_CHOICES = [
        ('U', 'User'),
        ('M', 'Moderator'),
        ('A', 'Admin'),
    ]
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default='U')
    confirmation_code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And i want to get JWT token, here is my urls

```
path("v1/token/", views.EmailTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name="token_obtain_pair")
```

i need send such POST query

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/token/
```

with data :

```
{ 'email': email, 'confirmation_code': confirmation_code }
```

but by default in simple-jwt i need to send data :

```
{'username' : username, 'password':password }
```

in my serializer.py

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    username_field = User.EMAIL_FIELD
```

in my views.py

```
class EmailTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

i have done to chane username on email, bun i can not chane password on confirmation_code

how can i change default way ?

Comment: Hello, where does `views.EmailTokenObtainPairView.as_view()` come from ?

Comment: hi, i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can override TokenObtainSerializer to customize.

For your case, you need to custom method `validate()`. Refer to this link https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html and https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/blob/c684e8396f8446cc289ed73a0740ca222c85470d/rest_framework_simplejwt/serializers.py#L20 for detail.