# How should I implement email verification using restframework-simple-JWT?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have been working on custom API token logic, that would allow me to verify users using **just their email**, but not username and password. How I see it:

1. One user send me credentials (just an email address);
2. Django SMTP server sends an email with verification code;
3. User sends its email address and verification code to the server and then gets access and refresh tokens;

I read approximately the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65693184/how-can-i-use-additional-fields-to-get-jwt-token), but I did not find the answer concrete enough, so I would be glad to hear any suggestion how to solve it.